# How to debug template in Meteor/handlebars?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

According to this [blog post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-3-tips-and-tricks), I should register a helper to better debug handlebars templates, but is not working:

`ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined`

So, how can I `{{debug}}` in Meteor/handlebars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness: you can also use

```
Template.registerHelper('helper', helperFunc);
```

instead of `Handlebars.regsterHelper('h',f);`

A small reason this is better is that then your app won't need that much refactoring if you decide somewhere down the road that you want to use something else instead of Handlebars(i.e. [Spacebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md), the real name of meteors adaption) like [jade for meteor](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade).

This is really a comment to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484415/2531091). Looking forward to one day hit 50 rep.

Comment: Meteor's api has changed, and it seems that for now on it should be like you said.

Answer (score 15):

This is the helper function I use for debugging in my own projects:

```
Template.registerHelper("debug", function(optionalValue) { 
  console.log("Current Context");
  console.log("====================");
  console.log(this);

  if (optionalValue) {
    console.log("Value"); 
    console.log("===================="); 
    console.log(optionalValue); 
  } 
});
```

You can then call it in your templates with `{{debug}}` and it displays the context you are currently in. Read more at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper.

Comment: excellent snippet, however, I guess Meteor recommends the notation `Template.myTemplate.helpers`.

Comment: yes, but then it will only be available in that specific template I believe

Comment: Yeah. I prefer to use your answer, because of this, but I guess the other notation is the *right* one.

Answer (score 6):

In Meteor 0.4.0 you register handlers like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  helper: function () {
    // some code here
    console.log(arguments);
  }
});
```

There is no need to call Handlebars directly.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you register your helper in client (or shared) meteor code.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function() {
  // Do stuff
});
```

This should be callable via `{{helper}}` in your templates.